Modify request parameters with Spring Rest Docs 3.x?
Spring Rest Docs 3.x removed the preprocessor to modify request parameters. In the release notes, it is unclear how to do it now. I would love to see an example of how it can be done now. Anybody has any idea?

What do you find unclear in the release notes? They state that "where parameter modification is required, the request’s URI should be updated to modify its query parameters or its form URL encoded body should be updated to modify its form parameters".

What I understand from the docs is to do this: andDo(document("my-endpoint", preprocessRequest(modifyUris())), but what method should I call on the modifyUris() return type? All I see there is methods to modify the scheme, host and port. Nothing about query parameters.

Thanks. The link to the pre-processor is misleading there, I'll update the release notes accordingly. Why not make the request with the required query parameters in the first place?

I wanted to remove the xsrf token that was added via Spring Security, but then I managed to fix it in a different way so it was not there as a query parameter any more. So currently, I have no need for it anymore, but removing something like that could be useful to somebody.
